# Emberjs not working when using url directly

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to EmberJs and was following [this](https://github.com/ahawkins/hawkins.io/blob/7c8f0984060a19611010eeb3d2963099c7b1f2e1/blog/_posts/2013-03-29-master-detail-views-with-ember.md) post from Adam Hawkins. When I tried to run this in a browser it seems to work but not as expected. when I click a dj in the navigation bar (data-template-name="djs") the browser navigates to the detail of the choosen dj and shows me all his albums. e.g. embertest/index.html#/djs/djs/armin-van-buuren

But if I paste the url (embertest/index.html#/djs/djs/armin-van-buuren) directly in the browser without clicking a dj first in the navigation list I get the message "No Albums" from the handlebars template "djs/dj"

I would expect the same behavior in both scenario's. What am I missing here?

For completeness you can find my ember application and handlebar templates below.

**app.js**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create(
{   LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_BINDINGS: true,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
    LOG_STACKTRACE_ON_DEPRECATION: true,
    LOG_VERSION: true,
    debugMode: true
});

window.App = App;

App.DJS = [
  { 
    name: 'Armin van Buuren',
    albums: [
      { 
        name: 'A State of Trance 2006',
        cover: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/87/ASOT_2006_cover.jpg/220px-ASOT_2006_cover.jpg'
      },
      { 
        name: '76',
        cover: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/8a/Armin_van_Buuren-76.jpg/220px-Armin_van_Buuren-76.jpg'
      },
      { 
        name: 'Shivers',
        cover: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a1/ArminvanBuuren_Shivers.png/220px-ArminvanBuuren_Shivers.png'
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    name: 'Markus Schulz',
    albums: [
      {
        name: 'Without You Near',
        cover: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/92/Markus_Schulz_Without_You_Near_album_cover.jpg'
      },
      { 
        name: 'Progression',
        cover: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/81/Markus-schulz-progression_cover.jpg/220px-Markus-schulz-progression_cover.jpg',
      },
      { 
        name: 'Do You Dream?',
        cover: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/92/Doyoudream.jpg/220px-Doyoudream.jpg',
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    name: 'Christopher Lawrence',
    albums: [
      {
        name: 'All or Nothing',
        cover: 'http://s.discogss.com/image/R-308090-1284903399.jpeg',
      },
      { 
        name: 'Un-Hooked: The Hook Sessions',
        cover: 'http://s.discogss.com/image/R-361463-1108759542.jpg'
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    name: 'Above & Beyond',
    albums: [
      {
        name: 'Group Therapy',
        cover: 'http://s.discogss.com/image/R-2920505-1345851845-3738.jpeg'
      },
      { 
        name: 'Tri-State',
        cover: 'http://s.discogss.com/image/R-634211-1141297400.jpeg',
      },
      { 
        name: 'Tri-State Remixed',
        cover: 'http://s.discogss.com/image/R-1206917-1200735829.jpeg'
      }
    ]
  }
];

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('djs', function() {
    this.route('dj', { path: '/djs/:name' });
  });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('djs');
  }
});

App.DjsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.DJS;
  }
});

App.DjsDjRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(dj) {
    return {
      name: dj.name.dasherize()
    }
  }
});
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<!-- application template -->
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      {{#linkTo 'djs' class="brand"}}On The Decks{{/linkTo}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="djs">
  <div class="span2">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
      {{#each controller}}
        <li>{{#linkTo 'djs.dj' this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="span8">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="djs/dj">
  <h2>{{name}}</h2>

  <h3>Albums</h3>

  {{#if albums}}
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      {{#each albums}}
        <li>
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img {{bindAttr src="cover" alt="name"}} />
          </div>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <p>No Albums</p>
  {{/if}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="djs/index">
  <p class="well">Please Select a DJ</p>
</script>

<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rigth, I try to explain you

Ember has severals ways to go to a Route, here we have two examples.

The linkTo helper, and directly writing the url.

With the linkTo we provide a model to the route, the *this* keyword

```
{{#linkTo 'djs.dj' this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}
```

For the url way, ember route needs to know the model to represent, and for this executes the model hook of the route (missing in your example), you can def the dj route like this.

```
App.DjsDjRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(dj) {
    return {
      name: dj.name.dasherize()
    }
  },
  model:function(dj){
      return App.DJS.find(function(item){
          //The url param is the dasherized name
          return item.name.dasherize() == dj.name;});
  }
});
```

Also there is a typo defining the routes and *this.route('dj', { path: '/djs/:name' });* should be **this.route('dj', { path: '/:name' });**

Complete JSFiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/AM7sf/10/show/#/djs